# Error : Connect with Dataverse using Client Id and Secret

Tags: .net, .net-core, dynamics-crm

I get this error while trying to connect to Dataverse:

> MsalClientException: Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but app://58145b91-0c36-4500-8554-080854f2ac97/ was found. Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication object. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Show us the relevant code and config you're using! Remember - we cannot see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind .... you need to ***SHOW US!***

Comment: This looks like an OAuth path exception. Can you share your connection string?